# What character encoding uses 2 underscores and a letter?

Tags: character-encoding

I'm currently parsing what looks to be a proprietary file format from a third-party commercial application. They seem to use a funny character encoding system and I need some help determining what it is, assuming it's not a proprietary encoding system as well.

I don't have a whole lot of different characters to analyze from but here is what I have so far:

```
__b -> blank space
__f -> forward slash
```

So for example, "Hello World" become "Hello__bWorld".

Does anybody have any idea what this is?

If not do you know of a resource on the web that can help me? Maybe there is a tool out there than can help in identifying character encoding?

Comment: Hopefully I don't have to recreate the mapping :\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be a proprietary encoding used by **Numara FootPrints**. This [list of mappings](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fpusergroup/message/5697) comes from the FootPrints User Group forum. There is also a Perl [script for decoding](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~awilkins/FootPrints/UnFix_Fields.pl) it.

```
Code Character
__b   (space)
__a ' (single quote)
__q " (double quote)
__t ` (backquote)
__m @ (at-sign)
__d . (period)
__u - (hyphen-minus)
__s ;
__c :
__p )
__P (
__3 #
__4 $
__5 %
__6 ^
__7 &
__8 *
__0 ~ (tilde)
__f / (slash)
__F \ (backslash)
__Q ?
__e ]
__E [
__g >
__G <
__B !
__W {
__w }
__C =
__A +
__I | (vertical line)
__M , (comma)
__Ux_ Unicode character with value 'x'
```

Comment: Right on target........ It is from Footprints... Impressive. I didn't think of mentioning Footprints as it doesn't seem like a very much discussed topic on the Web. Thank you.

Comment: To decode in C#, I used string.Replace() method ex: input.Replace("__b", " ");